# Imagen de fondo a tamaño completo css

Tags: html, css, web, responsive

Quiero que la imagen de fondo aparezca en tamaño completo sin tener que poner el height en pixeles, ya que no sería responsive. La imagen tiene que estar de fondo porque quiero poner las 3 imagenes rojas encima con enlaces si las pinchas.

Este es el codigo html y css:

```css
.map-section{
    padding: 3% 0 3% 0; 
    background-image: url("../images/world-map.png");
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}

.location-container{
    width: 33%;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 600px;
}

.location-point{
    margin: auto;
    align-items: center;
    width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<section class="map-section blue-background"> 
                <div class="location-container">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="location-point" src=images/location.png>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="location-container">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="location-point" src=images/location.png>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="location-container">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="location-point" src=images/location.png>
                    </a>
                </div>
        </section>
```

[image: Vista previa]

Comment: prueba con `vh` ejemplo: `width: 100vh;` `height: 100vh;` con estas medidas se te adaptan al ancho y largo de cualquier dispositivo.

Comment: cambiando eso el alto  se transforma en el de la imagen (el original en pixeles), pero no se adapta a la pantalla cuando cambias su tamaño.

Comment: tambien puedes probar con width: 1fr. Que significa una fraccion = abarcame todo el espacio disponible

Comment: background-size: cover; Coge la imagen y la pone extendiendo todo lo que pueda a lo alto y ancho sin dejar ningún punto vacío. Pero tal vez con eso... para poner los puntos de localización no sirva, tal vez con el position fixed del background?

Answer (score 1):

Te podría funcionar, si lo que estas buscando es que la imagen sea el fondo:

```
/* Tu imagen */
.background {
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat ;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

También podrías hacerlo sin que la imagen sea el fondo, utilizando propiedades de position:

```
.background{
position: absolute;
width: 100vh;
height: 100vh;
}


.icon{
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
top: 100px;
left:100px ;
}

*/ los iconos (en este caso los links) lo puedes acomodar con Top, Right, Left, Bottom
```

Espero te funcione